# How to collapse all groups in inbox Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, inbox

I want to toggle groups of messages in my inbox folder as below snapshot. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right-click on a **group** and select **Collapse All Groups** menu item.

Answer (score 3):

**Ctrl-Minus** is the keyboard shortcut for collapsing all groups.